# Xamarin attributed strings

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsattributedstring

I'm an iOS developer in the process of migrating to Xamarin.  One thing that comes to mind immediately is that I would love to have a cross-platform way of doing attributed strings.  Ideally, I would set the attributes once, in core code, then have a single "draw" command that went out to the appropriate platform-specific code to draw the attributed string.

Does such a thing exist?

EDIT: even the existence of a C# class that serves a purpose similar to NSAttributedString would be interesting information to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Xamarin.iOS` you can use the `NSAttributedString` just like you would while coding in `obj-C`.

But if I get your question right, you're mostly asking wether an abstraction for it exists so you could reuse the same attributed string on `Xamarin.iOS`, `Xamarin.Android` and even `WP`. Such a thing does not exists at the time (to my limited knowledge), but creating one does not look like rocket science.

Comment: That's pretty much correct.  As best I can tell, C# does not have an object that corresponds to NSAttributedString.  So I need to roll my own.